# Getting an object in resources by Key

Tags: c#, wpf

This should be a beginner's question to WPF but I can't find a simple answer. How do you get a handle on an object declared in WPF?

```
<Window x:Class="Testprj" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Testprj">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:CustomValidation x:Key="validationObj"/>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

If I'm not mistaken, the above code is creating an instance of a "CustomValidation" object with the key "validationObj". Now, say each "CustomValidation" object has an instance variable called "**myInstanceVar**", how can I get the value of myInstanceVar from the code behind?

What I'm trying to do is something like (pseudocode):

```
validationObj.myInstanceVar
```

But it's unable to find even "validationObj". Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking how you can reference an object in C# code that was instantiated (created) in WPF ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're asking how you can use that object from the code behind. I believe `this.FindResource("validationObj")` would do the trick.

```
var valObj = (CustomValidation)this.FindResource("validationObj");
var whatever = valObj.myInstanceVar;
```

Comment: Note that you'll have to cast the result to CustomValidation to access myInstanceVar.

Comment: I added the typecast to my example.

Answer (score 0):

you ask how to access control declared in XAML in codebehind

use x:name

than use poo in your codebehind

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290.aspx

generally you should not have a code behind and use the MVVM design pattern to avoid it.

this is a good place to start:
[MVVM: Tutorial from start to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish)